# Can't enter WiFi password on Moto G since Lollipop update

Tags: wi-fi, 5.0-lollipop, motorola-moto-g

My `Moto G` upgraded to Lollipop yesterday and since then when I want to use my work WiFi I can't find where to key in the password. The Icon shows a `"?"` and the WiFi menu says `'connected'` but I cannot use it.

How can I key in the password?

Comment: Forget the network and then reconnect?